# How to insert a html file that references other scripts in cshtml file?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, network-drive

I have a html file on a network drive (the same network my where my server runs) and I want to show it to the users. So I tried to do the following:

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText("//path/on/netwotk/drive.html")
```

The problem is that html file references other files in the same folder (mostly js scripts)
And the server tries to look for them in his url (`localhost/relative/path/to/file`) instead of in the network drive.

How can I tell the server to look for the files in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is extremely bad practice. You shouldn't be doing it this way.

**How this works**

When you call the following method:

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText("//path/on/netwotk/drive.html")
```

the HTML helper runs on your server side. It loads all the content from the file you have specified and sends it to the browser exactly the way it's written in the file. And it only reads that specific file and nothing but that file.

The client-side markup in your browser doesn't know anything about the folder on your network drive. It just can't possibly know it. The browser can be on anyone's device.

When your browser sees relative paths in the HTML markup, it will try to send a GET HTTP request to obtain those. And the address it will be using will have the same base URL that it got its original page from followed by the relative path, as specified in the HTML. And it cannot find it, because there is no such thing. That file doesn't exist at that address.

The paths that you see in HTML are not relative to the folder structure. They are relative to the address that the browser can access. It's just that if you place the static resources into actual folder on your host, those paths will map to the paths after the base URL in the browser.

**What you should do instead**

There is no scenario in real life where you would want to access HTML, JavaScript and CSS via some remote folder. Just place them into the folder on the actual host machine. They should be part of your actual application. It is totally acceptable to have multiple copies of those for multiple environments.

In the context of ASP.NET application, those resources are known as static files. And you can enable those, as if you are running an old-school website. This is where you can find the documentation on how to work with them:

[Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)

Your other alternative is to rewrite the code from those HTML files and put it into your Razor views.

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this is because this html file is a tutorial and I want it to be easily updated without the need to reupload the whole backend

Comment: It would not be possible to get it to link to other files in a remote folder. Your hosting server will not be able to serve it to the browser. If you absolute need to load the file from a network drive, then the only way to achieve what you want is to put all other HTML, CSS and JavaScript into the same file.